# How add blank line in messages django?

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I have a line of my code

**messages.error(request, 'A soma das despesas correntes e das despesas de capital ultrapassam o valor total do projeto.')**

popping up a message in my template

**A soma das despesas correntes e das despesas de capital ultrapassam o valor total do projeto.**

But I want to get a new line after the point, like:

```
A soma das despesas correntes e das despesas de capital,
ultrapassam o valor total do projeto.
```

How do I get that?

I tryed

**A soma das despesas correntes e das despesas de capital, \n ultrapassam o valor total do projeto.**

and

**A soma das despesas correntes e das despesas de capital, < br \> ultrapassam o valor total do projeto.**

and

**{{ message|linebreak }}**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the extra_tags for this:

```
messages.error(request, 'A soma das despesas correntes e das despesas de capital <br> ultrapassam o valor total do projeto.', extra_tags='safe')
```

Now in template

```
{% for message in messages %}
    {{message|safe}}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `{{ message|linebreak }}`, try: `{{ message|safe }}`.

The `safe` filter will make your text be rendered as HTML, then `<br>` should work.

Tamo junto